# NotifyPropertyChanged and ContentControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I am struggling for one week now with my problem and i cant solve it. I am programming a MVVM WPF application which is having one window (MainView). In This `Mainview` i want to load different `UserControl` when i need them. In the `Application-Startup` I am loading the `MainViewModel`. In the Constructor of the `MainViewModel` I am loading the First `ViewModel` (`LoginViewModel`). Cause of my `MainView.xaml` it is showing me my `Login-User-Control` like i want to. So till this point everything is fine. In the `ActivePanel-class` i am saving the `CurrentView`, because in my `MainView.xaml` i am making a binding to my `CurrentView` for the `ContentControl`. So everything is working except the changing of the views although my `NotifyPropertyChanged` method of the `CurrentView` is working. I am thinking, that my mistake is in the `xaml` (DataBinding). Hope you guys can help me.

This is my `MainView.xaml` in which i want to load the different DataTemplates. Like I said before: The loading of the `LoginViewModel` via the Constructor of `MainViewModel` is working. The changing to other `VieModels` is working as well, but the DataBinding to the `ContentControl` is the big problem here.

```
<Window x:Class="App.View.MainView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App.View"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:App.ViewModels"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:App.View"
        xmlns:helper="clr-namespace:App.Helper"
        Title="Betrooms" Height="500" Width="350">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="LoginUCTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:LoginViewModel}">
            <views:LoginUC DataContext="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Name="RegUCTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:RegViewModel}">
            <views:RegUC DataContext="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Name="HomeUCTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:HomeViewModel}">
            <views:HomeUC DataContext="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewmodels:ActivePanel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is the class of my `ActivePanel` where i am saving the information about which `ViewModel` is the active one. The `CurrentView` is the property I am binding the Content Control to.

```
namespace APP.ViewModels
{
    public class ActivePanel : NotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private object _currentView;

        public object CurrentView
        {
            get { return _currentView; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _currentView)
                {
                    _currentView = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("CurrentView");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `MainViewModel`:

```
namespace App.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : ActivePanel
    {
        private LoginViewModel _loginViewModel;

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            _loginViewModel = new LoginViewModel();
            CurrentView = _loginViewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my `LoginViewModel` where I am changing the value of `CurrentView` via an action:

```
namespace App.ViewModels
{
    public class LoginViewModel : ActivePanel
    {
        #region Member
        private string _username;
        private string _password;
        bool login = false;

        private HomeViewModel _homeViewModel;
        private RegViewModel _regViewModel;

        UserModel User = new UserModel();
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        public ICommand RegActionCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand LogActionCommand { get; set; }

        public string GetUsername
        {
            get { return _username; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _username)
                {
                    _username = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("GetUsername");
                }
            }
        }

        public string GetPassword
        {
            get { return _password; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _password)
                {
                    _password = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("GetPassword");
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public LoginViewModel()
        {
            this.RegActionCommand = new RelayCommand(RegAction);
            this.LogActionCommand = new RelayCommand(LogAction);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Button-Action
        private void LogAction(object obj)
        {               
                _homeViewModel = new HomeViewModel();
                CurrentView = _homeViewModel;
        }

        private void RegAction(object obj)
        {
            _regViewModel = new RegViewModel();
            CurrentView = _regViewModel;
        }
        #endregion           
    }
}
```

I hope my question is understandable: The `ContenControl` binding is set to `CurrentView` but the `ContentControl` is never changing although the property of `CurrentView` is changing.

Thanks to you all. Cheers, Paul.

Comment: Have you tried defining your content control data templates under the `ContentControl` instead of the Window resources?

Comment: I do not think that i have tried this. I am not very familiar with this kind of coding. I tried a lot of thinks which i found on google but nothing worked. Do you think, you could give a little example of how to form my MainView.xaml?

Comment: As a note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on a OneWay Binding is pointless. It only has an effect on TwoWay or OneWayToSource Bindings. And setting `Mode=OneWay` is redundant, because that's the default.

Comment: That said, how is your code supposed to work? There is an `ActivePanel` instance set as the DataContext of the MainWindow, with a `CurrentView` that is initially null. How does that property ever change?

Comment: Thanks for your information about the {Mode=OneWay}. I have changed that. To your other questions about the CurrentView: Like I have understood that i can follow the value of CurrentView while runtime and yes, at the start of the programm the value is null but the constructor turns into LoginVIewModel. When I hit a Button in die LoginViewModel the value of CurrentView Changes again. So this is all working but the binding to CurrentView doesnt. I hope you can say more in detail about what to change. Cheers, Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your command handler, you are changing the `CurrentView` property of your `LoginViewModel`. The `ContentControl`'s `DataContext` is the `MainViewModel` though, so it's content is bound to the `CurrentView` property of the `MainViewModel`.

You need to set the `MainViewModel`'s property in your command handler. There are different ways of achieving this, for example you could add a constructor parameter to the `LoginViewModel` to pass a reference to the `MainViewModel`. You can save this reference and then access it in your command handler.

Another possibilty would be to raise an event or send a message from the command in your `LoginViewModel` and handle it in the `MainViewModel`. This would reduce the coupling between your ViewModels, but depending on which mechanism and library you use it might be a little bit more complicated.

Comment: Thank you. I am understanding now what is wrong in my code.